# making client side notifications of a timeout in rails using devise timeout_in and timeoutable

Tags: session, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there any way rails devise can warn a user before the timeout happens, or just timeout on its own (without doing a post) once the timeout_in time is met? I suspect it needs some sort of jquery on the client side, but I'm not sure how to implement this to make this play nice with `devise#timeout_in`. Googling around, I didn't find much - is there a specific technical term I should be Googling to find more helpful information?

Comment: I recently asked a duplicate of this question and didn't get any answers either. It looks like we have to roll out our own components to achieve this functionality... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734332

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question myself. The only thing I can suggest (far from ideal) is putting in a javascript countdown equal to the timeoutable value (like 10 minutes or whatever) MINUS the warning threshold.

This countdown will get reset anytime ANY input happens from the user. So if you set it to 9 minutes and timeoutable is 10, you show a warning accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this gem
https://github.com/pelargir/auto-session-timeout

fork it and have it return with the active ajax call the time left for the session