# Devise - Make a request without resetting the countdown until a user is logged out due to inactivity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm working on a RoR app with Devise. I want to let clients send a request to the server to see how much time is left until the user on the client is automatically logged out due to inactivity (using the `Timeoutable` module). I don't want this request to cause Devise to reset the countdown until the user is logged off. How can I configure this?

This is the code I have now:

```
class SessionTimeoutController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # Calculates the number of seconds until the user is
  # automatically logged out due to inactivity. Unlike most
  # requests, it should not reset the timeout countdown itself.
  def check_time_until_logout
    @time_left = current_user.timeout_in
  end

  # Determines whether the user has been logged out due to
  # inactivity or not. Unlike most requests, it should not reset the
  # timeout countdown itself.
  def has_user_timed_out
    @has_timed_out = current_user.timedout? (Time.now)
  end

  # Resets the clock used to determine whether to log the user out
  # due to inactivity.
  def reset_user_clock
    # Receiving an arbitrary request from a client automatically
    # resets the Devise Timeoutable timer.
    head :ok
  end
end
```

`SessionTimeoutController#reset_user_clock` works because every time RoR receives a request from an authenticated user, `Timeoutable#timeout_in` is reset to whatever I have configured in  `Devise#timeout_in`. How do I prevent that reset in `check_time_until_logout` and `has_user_timed_out`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I ended up having to make several changes to my code. I'll show what I ended up with when I was finished, then explain what it does:

```
class SessionTimeoutController < ApplicationController
  # These are what prevent check_time_until_logout and
  # reset_user_clock from resetting users' Timeoutable
  # Devise "timers"
  prepend_before_action :skip_timeout, only: [:check_time_until_logout, :has_user_timed_out]
  def skip_timeout
    request.env["devise.skip_trackable"] = true
  end

  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:has_user_timed_out]

  def check_time_until_logout
    @time_left = Devise.timeout_in - (Time.now - user_session["last_request_at"]).round
  end

  def has_user_timed_out
    @has_timed_out = (!current_user) or (current_user.timedout? (user_session["last_request_at"]))
  end

  def reset_user_clock
    # Receiving an arbitrary request from a client automatically
    # resets the Devise Timeoutable timer.
    head :ok
  end
end
```

These are the changes I made:

**Using `env["devise.skip_trackable"]`**

This is the code that prevents Devise from resetting how long it waits before logging a user out due to inactivity:

```
  prepend_before_action :skip_timeout, only: [:check_time_until_logout, :has_user_timed_out]
  def skip_timeout
    request.env["devise.skip_trackable"] = true
  end
```

This code changes a hash value that Devise uses internally to decide whether to update the value it stores to keep track of when the user last had activity. Specifically, this is the Devise code we're interacting with ([link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb)):

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |record, warden, options|
  scope = options[:scope]
  env   = warden.request.env

  if record && record.respond_to?(:timedout?) && warden.authenticated?(scope) && options[:store] != false
    last_request_at = warden.session(scope)['last_request_at']

    if record.timedout?(last_request_at) && !env['devise.skip_timeout']
      warden.logout(scope)
      if record.respond_to?(:expire_auth_token_on_timeout) && record.expire_auth_token_on_timeout
        record.reset_authentication_token!
      end
      throw :warden, :scope => scope, :message => :timeout
    end

    unless env['devise.skip_trackable']
      warden.session(scope)['last_request_at'] = Time.now.utc
    end
  end
end
```

(Note that this code is executed every time that Rails processes a request from a client.)

These lines near the end are interesting to us:

```
    unless env['devise.skip_trackable']
      warden.session(scope)['last_request_at'] = Time.now.utc
    end
```

This is the code that "resets" the countdown until the user is logged out due to inactivity. It's only executed if `env['devise.skip_trackable']` is not `true`, so we need to change that value before Devise processes the user's request.

To do that, we tell Rails to change the value of `env['devise.skip_trackable']` before it does anything else. Again, from my final code:

```
  prepend_before_action :skip_timeout, only: [:check_time_until_logout, :has_user_timed_out]
  def skip_timeout
    request.env["devise.skip_trackable"] = true
  end
```

---

Everything above this point is what I needed to change to answer my question. There were a couple other changes I needed to make to get my code to work as I wanted, though, so I'll document them here, too.

**Using `Timeoutable` Correctly**

I misread the documentation about the `Timeoutable` module, so my code in my question has a couple other problems.

First, my `check_time_until_logout` method was going to always return the same value. This is the incorrect version of the action I had:

```
def check_time_until_logout
  @time_left = current_user.timeout_in
end
```

I thought that `Timeoutable#timeout_in` would return the amount of time until the user was automatically logged out. Instead, it returns the amount of time that Devise is configured to wait before logging users out. We need to calculate how much longer the user has left ourselves.

To calculate this, we need to know when the user last had activity that Devise recognized. This code, from the Devise source we looked at above, determines when the user was last active:

```
    last_request_at = warden.session(scope)['last_request_at']
```

We need to get a handle to the object returned by `warden.session(scope)`. It looks like the `user_session` hash, which Devise provides for us like the handles `current_user` and `user_signed_in?`, is that object.

Using the `user_session` hash and calculating the time remaining ourselves, the `check_time_until_logout` method becomes

```
  def check_time_until_logout
    @time_left = Devise.timeout_in - (Time.now - user_session["last_request_at"]).round
  end
```

I also misread the documentation for `Timeoutable#timedout?`. It checks to see if the user has timed out when you pass in the time the user was last active, *not* when you pass in the current time. The change we need to make is straightforward: instead of passing in `Time.now`, we need to pass in the time in the `user_session` hash:

```
  def has_user_timed_out
    @has_timed_out = (!current_user) or (current_user.timedout? (user_session["last_request_at"]))
  end
```

Once I made these three changes, my controller acted the way I expected it to.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks for the code sample! Using this code with rails 4.2.6, and devise 3.5.6 I had a couple of errors to fix; `NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `-@'` is fixed by changing `@time_left = Devise.timeout_in - (Time.now - user_session["last_request_at"]).round` to `@time_left = Devise.timeout_in - (Time.now - user_session["last_request_at"]).to_i`

Comment: And the error `ArgumentError Exception: comparison of Fixnum with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone failed` is fixed by changing the line `@has_timed_out = (!current_user) or (current_user.timedout? (user_session["last_request_at"]))` to `@has_timed_out = (!current_user) or (current_user.timedout? (Time.at(user_session["last_request_at"])))`

Comment: How to send a alert message to the client before devise timeout?

Comment: @CharanKumarBorra In our solution, we wrote some client-side JavaScript that pinged the server about once a minute to see how much longer the user could wait before being logged out. Once there was about 1 minute left, that code showed the user a message.

Comment: Can you please share client-side Javascript code. So that I can try to use it for my application.

Comment: Your code to check the remaining time to logout is wrong, it always retrieve nil. This is the right code:
`seconds = Devise.timeout_in.seconds - (Time.now.to_i - user_session["last_request_at"]).round`

Answer (score 17):

when i see this correctly (probably depending on the devise version) devise handles the logout through the `Timeoutable` module.

this is hooked up to warden, which is part of the rack middleware stack.

if you look at the code, than you can find this part:

```
unless warden.request.env['devise.skip_trackable']
  warden.session(scope)['last_request_at'] = Time.now.utc
end
```

so from what i can see here, you should be able to set `devise.skip_trackable` to true before the warden middleware get's called.

i think that this issue here explains how to actually use it: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/953

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty because your answer gave me the push I needed to figure out what I was doing. I'm accepting my answer because I think that since I provide a code sample showing exactly how to deal with my issue, it will be more useful for future readers. Thank you for your help! =D

Answer (score 3):

The two leading answers of prepending a `request.env["devise.skip_trackable"] = true` action did not work for me initially.

It seems that this only works if you are using the "classic" `authenticate_user!` before action, and not when using authenticated routes. If you are using authenticated routes in your `config/routes.rb`, such as:

```
authenticate :user do
  resources :some_resources
end
```

Prepending the action does not seem to affect the Devise chain in time, so you should comment out the `authenticate` block out, use an `authenticate_user!` before action instead in your `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`, and add a prepend action that sets `skip_trackable` to true in a specific controller.

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 6 and Devise 4.7.1, this is working for me, thanks to the selected and bounty answers.

```rb
# controller

prepend_before_action :skip_trackable, only: :update, if: -> { request.format.js? }

private

def skip_trackable
  request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true
  request.env["devise.skip_trackable"] = true
end
```

The [Devise code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb) that the selected answer referenced has a new section:

```rb
if !env['devise.skip_timeout'] &&
    record.timedout?(last_request_at) &&
    !proxy.remember_me_is_active?(record)
  Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? proxy.sign_out : proxy.sign_out(scope)
  throw :warden, scope: scope, message: :timeout
end
```

This required also setting `devise.skip_timeout`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Any chance you know how to send the user a notification when they are about to be logged out?

Comment: No, but seems like you could hook into the `last_request_at` and figure out how much time they have left and send them a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for time left is incorrect. The right calculation will be:

```rb
def check_time_until_logout
  @time_left = Devise.timeout_in.seconds - (Time.now.to_i - user_session["last_request_at"]).round
end
```