# 2 minutes before session timeout, warn the user and extend it with Devise | Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

To auto logout user for being `idle/inactive` till 20 minutes. I have used Devise module **[`:timeoutable`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Timeoutable)** and also set `config.timeout_in = 20.minutes` in devise configuration file. Which works perfectly fine.

Now when user have been inactive in the application for 18 minutes, would like to notify him

> "You will be sign-out after 2 minutes due to your inactivity. If you
>   wish to continue your session press Ok"

To achieve this I have added `setInterval()` function inside **application.js** which will make Ajax call each minute to check user's session (I have set expire time manually in session as below).

**application_controller.rb:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :renew_user_session

  def renew_user_session
    session[:expires_at] = (Time.now + 20.minutes).to_s
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :renew_user_session, only: :validate_user_session

  # this method is called in setInterval() through ajax
  def validate_user_session
    status = true
    if user_signed_in?
      status = (Time.parse(session[:expires_at]) - 2.minutes) > Time.now
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: status }
    end
  end
end
```

but whenever I make Ajax call, it activate user. Is there anyway to check user's inactivity time? and notify before 2 minutes? or any alternate solution to achieve this?

Comment: Websockets would do, but it’s probably an overkill here.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin but it will also make request to application and make user active. not sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Devise - Make a request without resetting the countdown until a user is logged out due to inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791626/devise-make-a-request-without-resetting-the-countdown-until-a-user-is-logged-o)

Comment: @mrzasa thanks mate. `request.env["devise.skip_trackable"] = true` this what I needed.