# Will a user be automatically redirected to login page when using devise gem in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, session-timeout

I am considering using `devise` gem for authentication. I have an important question though.

If a user's session times out, will the user be automatically redirected to login screen if I use `devise`? Or will the user be redirected only if the user performs some action on the UI after timeout?

Is it possible to display a timeout warning using `devise`? For example, say 120 seconds before timeout, is it possible to display a countdown timer warning the user that the session would timeout soon in the time shown by the timer?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user's session is expired then devise will redirect it to the sign in page.

If you want to alert the user for the session expiration you can look these options

1. session timeout prompter gem
   https://github.com/epigenesys/session-timeout-prompter
2. some code modification as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791626/devise-make-a-request-without-resetting-the-countdown-until-a-user-is-logged-o)

Comment: thanks much for your response. I have 2 questions please 1. The GitHub page says they assume we are using devise timeout table. So, should we use devise in order for this gem to work? 2. The GitHub page says we need to include this code after the body in the view where the timer should be displayed : `= init_session_timeout_prompter(session_timeout_in_seconds: User.timeout_in.to_i, seconds_to_warn_before_timeout: 305, scope: :user)`. Should this code be used inside `<script>` tag after the `<body>...</body>` tag?

Comment: yes you need to use devise gem as well as need to make your model timeoutable

Comment: Sorry for the second question that you need to do the trial and error

Comment: can you please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it :)

Comment: I have accepted the answer but if you could give any pointers to the second question that'd really helpful

Comment: Sure... I will let you know if I get any clue.. thanks