# Why isn't "expiry" header updated with each new request to Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

I'm using Devise `:timeoutable` module to make session expire after some time of inactivity. Timeout is reset with each new request, so the session expiry date is shifted. But it's just not reflected in the `expiry` header sent in response to the client.

I noticed that `expiry` response header is constant for all XHRs that I send to the server. Even after refreshing the page, the `expiry` header is not updated. In other words, the value of the header is correct only for the very first request I send after sign-in, and then it remains constant.

There is no relevant code to demonstrate since Devise appends auth headers to every response out of the box.

Here is how the **response headers** look like:

```
access-token: qK5XalnvENIXJDHGCKJ5_A
Cache-Control: no-cache
client: c-4_msWmyUFD7PwD7fPW5Q
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2019 15:52:32 GMT
expiry: 1556548396
Server: nginx
token-type: Bearer
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
uid: user@email.com
Vary: Origin
X-Request-Id: 2fa70ebf-dcf2-4680-8c25-68d7b5e12b1b
X-Runtime: 0.021004
```

And the **request headers** (if relevant):

```
GET /api/user/context HTTP/1.1
Host: qa.whiz.ai:9060
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
access-token: qK5XalnvENIXJDHGCKJ5_A
client: c-4_msWmyUFD7PwD7fPW5Q
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
expiry: 1556548396
uid: user@email.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36
token-type: Bearer
Referer: https://my-page.example.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,uk-UA;q=0.8,uk;q=0.7,ru-UA;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5
Cookie: ...
```

I tried removing `expiry` from request headers, but it has no effect.

Is it expected behavior? Shouldn't Devise send actual value in that header out of the box?

I would like to know the actual expiration time to be able to perform some actions on the client. For this I could try solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791626/devise-make-a-request-without-resetting-the-countdown-until-a-user-is-logged-o), but would be much simpler if I could take advantage of the header already present in every response.

Comment: Well, the expiry header is not used for authentication. Rather its a cache control mechanism so that the client can cache requests without getting stale.

Comment: It has something to do with devise token authentication, doesn't it?
Here is the related source: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/user.rb#L171

But then I completely misunderstand the purpose of that header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devises Timeoutable module has absolutely nothing to do with the expiry headers. Just because two concepts may seem similar does not mean the are related.

Timeoutable stores `last_request_at` in the session (which is cookie storage by default).

You can get the value with:

```
ENV['warden'].session(scope)['last_request_at']
```

Where `scope` is based on the name of your model .

From [the source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/f39c6fd92774cb66f96f546d8d5e8281542b4e78/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb):

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |record, warden, options|
  scope = options[:scope]
  env   = warden.request.env

  if record && record.respond_to?(:timedout?) && warden.authenticated?(scope) &&
     options[:store] != false && !env['devise.skip_timeoutable']
    last_request_at = warden.session(scope)['last_request_at']

    if last_request_at.is_a? Integer
      last_request_at = Time.at(last_request_at).utc
    elsif last_request_at.is_a? String
      last_request_at = Time.parse(last_request_at)
    end

    proxy = Devise::Hooks::Proxy.new(warden)

    if record.timedout?(last_request_at) &&
        !env['devise.skip_timeout'] &&
        !proxy.remember_me_is_active?(record)
      Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? proxy.sign_out : proxy.sign_out(scope)
      throw :warden, scope: scope, message: :timeout
    end

    unless env['devise.skip_trackable']
      warden.session(scope)['last_request_at'] = Time.now.utc.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

The expiry header is instead used to control the caching of each separate response. The heuristics of how and when a client should consider a specify response stale are pretty complicated but the expiry header contains a timestamp of when the response should be expired.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it's related to timeoutable, but I see it's something different (found source here: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/user.rb#L171)

Comment: Yeah its more like a basic tennet of how caching in HTTP works. Sure devise token authentication may use expiry headers buts it not more tied to that than a screw is to a rocket.

Comment: but anyway, how can it be useful for determining when the response should be expired, if it is not updated for newer responses? E.g. it's *9:00pm* now, my `expiry` header might contain outdated timestamp like *8:55pm* - is it expected behavior or some misconfiguration?

Comment: The thing is that that response has `Cache-Control: no-cache` which means that the expiry header will not be used anyways.

Comment: Heroku has a pretty decent writeup on how HTTP caching works. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers